# How to trick a Linux program into "seeing" just the loopback network interface lo0?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, loopback

The title says it all. I am trying to avoid the situation when a program detects the IP of a network interface and sends it to a remote location. I am thinking to do this by tricking the program into seeing only the loopback network interface, so all it could find would be 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by dstorefile1 in a comment, if you create a network namespace (easiest way, using iproute2 and doing "ip netns add carcel") then by running a program in that namespace ("ip netns exec carcel yourProgram") it will be by default only see a loopback interface.

Here "carcel" is the name of the network namespace.

Comment: Tested with `ip addr show` running in the network namespace. It works as expected. Thank you.